# cannot bind event to object method

Tags: vue.js, events, methods, binding

I have a vue single file component, which have a custom class instance as property: now i want to bind a event to a method of this class instance but i'm having issues, there is a simplified version of my code files

#### VueJS single file component

```js
    <template>
        <div @click="class_prop.method"></div>
    </template>

    export default {
      data() {
        return {
            class_prop: new CustomClass(),
        };
      },
    }
```

#### CustomClass

```js
    class CustomClass {
        constructor(){
            this.prop = 'default_value';
        }

        method(){
            this.prop = 'new_value';
            console.log(this.prop);
        }
    }
```

#### The error

When clicking on the page element i receive this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of null"
```

But when i try to call the custom class method from the  browser console (i'm using Chrome with Vue Devtools extension) i get NO error, it works correctly:

```
$vm0.class_prop.method()
```

Since i get two different behaviours of my code i cannot tell if it is my class wrong, the vue single file component, or something else.

Comment: Try: `@click="() => class_prop.method()"`

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes your solution work correctly, evenf if i can't figure out why and it means that vue js has 2 different behaviours for binding nested props and binding nested methods; if you write your comment as answer i'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes Vue *somehow* called or applied your method using `null`. Thus the error you've mentioned:

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of null"

---

What can you do to workaround the problem?

You can use a lambda expression, so you can have full control of the object owner of the `method`, like this:

```html
<div @click="() => class_prop.method()"></div>
```

You can also use the class instance in a method like this:

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    foo: new CustomClass(),
  }),
  methods: {
    bar() {
      this.foo.method();
    },
  },
}
```

And then in your template:

```html
<div @click="bar">{{ foo.prop }}</div>
```

Comment: But not exactly correct - the linked code is used only if there are some event modifiers (see [lines 109-120](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/b51430f598b354ed60851bb62885539bd25de3d8/src/compiler/codegen/events.js#L109))

Answer (score 1):

What you see is not Vue's fault, it's just plain JavaScript.

Here is a citation from [great JS learning resource](https://javascript.info/object-methods)

> The consequences of unbound `this`

> If you come from another programming language, then you are probably used to the idea of a "bound this", where methods defined in an object always have `this` referencing that object.
> In JavaScript `this` is “free”, its value is evaluated at call-time and does not depend on where the method was declared, but rather on what object is “before the dot”.

Here is very simple example of consequences of above paragraphs (and why your code does not work):

```js
class CustomClass {
  constructor() {
    this.prop = 'default_value';
  }

  method() {
    this.prop = 'new_value';
    console.log(this.prop);
  }
}

let instance = new CustomClass()

instance.method() // this works OK

let f = instance.method

f() // this does not! f is "unbound" ....have no "this"
```

Comment: I don't think so. In your example it throws error on undefined. In the OP code it throws error on `null`, which means somewhere vue called `f.call(null, ...args)` ... Maybe just `data` is not the _place_ to have methods in vue :/

Comment: So ? Maybe Vue is doing something there but the point is without calling the method using the original instance, `this` is unbound. that's it...